# Can I create a Python Numpy ufunc from an unbound member method?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to use numpy.frompyfunc to generate an unbound ufunc from an unbound member method.  My concrete but failing attempts look like

```
class Foo(object):
    def f(x,y,z):
        return x + y + z

Foo.g = numpy.frompyfunc(Foo.f,3,1)
i = Foo()
i.g(5,6,7)
```

where the last line fails with
"TypeError: unbound method f() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got int instance instead)". That error makes sense to me as Foo.f is unbound.

Despite it being deprecated, I thought I'd give new.instancemethod a shot:

```
import new
Foo.h = new.instancemethod(numpy.frompyfunc(Foo.f,3,1),None,Foo)
j = Foo()
j.h(5,6,7)
```

where the last line now fails with "TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType" which I don't understand.

My goal is to monkey patch Foo with ufunc-ready versions of its members.  They must be member methods as they depend on a Foo instance's state (though that dependency is not shown here).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

class Foo(object):
    def f(self,x,y,z):
        return x + y + z
```

Add a `g` method to `Foo`:

```
def g(self,x,y,z):
    return np.frompyfunc(self.f,3,1)(x,y,z)
Foo.g = g
```

Calling `g` from an instance of `Foo`:

```
i = Foo()
print(i.g(np.array([5,6]),np.array([6,7]),np.array([7,8])))
# [18 21]
```

Comment: Excellent.  Exactly what I needed.  I've additionally added an 'out=None' parameter to g to match the usual ufunc usage.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I must admit that I don't quite understand why you'd want f and g to be inside Foo class, but the following works:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @staticmethod
...     def f(x, y, z):
...             return x+y+z
...
>>> Foo.g = numpy.frompyfunc(Foo.f, 3, 1)
>>> i = Foo()
>>> i.g(5, 6, 7)
18
```

EDIT: since you want to use instance data in your method, what you actualy need is a *bound* method:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def f(self, x, y, z):
...             return x+y+z
...
>>> i = Foo()
>>> i.g = numpy.frompyfunc(i.f, 3, 1)
>>> i.g(5, 6, 7)
18
```

Of course, in real code you will probably want to assign g in `Foo.__init__` , not outside of the class:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.g = numpy.frompyfunc(self.f, 3, 1)
...     def f(self, x, y, z):
...             return x+y+z
...
>>> i = Foo()
>>> i.g(5, 6, 7)
18
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  I'd like f and g inside Foo as in reality (i.e. outside of this cooked example) my Foo contains nontrivial member data used by f(x,y,z).  The @staticmethod approach doesn't quite fit my needs as declaring f(x,y,z) static doesn't allow access to the data members.

Comment: Oh, then you want a normal bound method. See above.

Comment: Your use of \_\_init\_\_(self) as a way to generate a bound method makes perfect sense (thank you), but I'm afraid my use case doesn't allow me to access to \_\_init_\_ as Foo is generated by SWIG (unless it's possible to add code to \_\_init\_\_ using the Foo class object).

Also, subclassing Foo to get access to the subclass' \_\_init\_\_ won't work either as SWIG will be using Foo and not the subclass.